# template class gives error with boost type

Tags: templates, boost, c++11, constexpr

I'm trying to implement a `template` class (named `Modular`) in order to make some modular operations such as sums and multiplications.

`int` and `int64_t` work fine, but if I try passing boost integer types such as `int128_t` or `mpz_int`, the compiler outputs a few errors that I don't understand very well.

Here's the class code:

```
template <class T, int64_t modulus>
class Modular {
public:
    Modular() : num_(0) { }
    Modular(const T& num = 0) : num_(num % modulus) { }
    Modular(const Modular& other) : num_(other.num_) { }
    ~Modular() { }

    T get() const { return num_; }

    Modular& operator=(const Modular& other) { num_ = other.num_; return *this; }
    bool operator==(const Modular& other) { return num_ == other.num_; }
    bool operator!=(const Modular& other) { return num_ != other.num_; }
    Modular& operator++() { ++num_; num_ %= modulus; return *this; }
    Modular operator++(int) { Modular temp(*this); operator++(); return temp; }
    Modular& operator+=(const Modular& other) { num_ += other.num_; num_ %= modulus; return *this; }
    Modular& operator-=(const Modular& other) { num_ -= other.num_; num_ %= modulus; return *this; }
    Modular& operator*=(const Modular& other) { num_ *= other.num_; num_ %= modulus; return *this; }

    Modular& operator/=(const Modular& other)
    {
        if((num_ % other.num_) == 0)
            num_ /= other.num_;
        else
        {
            Modular temp(0);
            while(temp * other != num_)
                ++temp;
            num_ = temp.num_;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    Modular pow(const T& exp)
    {
        if(exp == 1)
            return *this;

        Modular square(num_ * num_ % modulus);

        if(exp & 1)
            return (*this) * square.pow(exp/2);
        else
            return square.pow(exp/2);
    }

protected:
    T num_;
};

template <class T, T modulus>
inline Modular<T, modulus> operator+(const Modular<T, modulus>& lhs, const Modular<T, modulus>& rhs)
{
    Modular<T, modulus> temp(lhs);
    temp += rhs;
    return temp;
}

template <class T, T modulus>
inline Modular<T, modulus> operator-(const Modular<T, modulus>& lhs, const Modular<T, modulus>& rhs)
{
    Modular<T, modulus> temp(lhs);
    temp -= rhs;
    return temp;
}

template <class T, T modulus>
inline Modular<T, modulus> operator*(const Modular<T, modulus>& lhs, const Modular<T, modulus>& rhs)
{
    Modular<T, modulus> temp(lhs);
    temp *= rhs;
    return temp;
}

template <class T, T modulus>
inline Modular<T, modulus> operator/(const Modular<T, modulus>& lhs, const Modular<T, modulus>& rhs)
{
    Modular<T, modulus> temp(lhs);
    temp /= rhs;
    return temp;
}
```

Here's `main()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

using boost::multiprecision::int128_t;

int main()
{
    const int128_t n = 123;
    const int64_t mod = 456;

    typedef Modular<int128_t, mod> mint;

    const mint a = static_cast<int128_t)(789);
    const mint b = static_cast<int128_t)(12);

    mint result(0);

    for(mint x(1); x != mint(101); ++x){
        result += (a * x.pow(n+2) + b * x.pow(n+1) - x) / mint(x*x + x - mint(1));
    }
    std::cout << result.get();

    return 0;
}
```

And the compiler output: http://pastebin.com/1fNgDedt

Initially I used `const int128_t mod` but the compiler said that `mod` must be defined `constexpr` so i replaced with it, but i can't understand why and I can't understand at all the first compiler's error.

Comment: It seems like the compiler doesn't consider `int128_t` to be an integral type. Not sure why though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your specific platform, boost defines, `int128_t` as `boost::multiprecision::number<>`, because your platform does not provide a 128bit builtin intgeral type. In C++, only integral data types are allowed as template parameters, so `int128_t`, despite the typedef's name *looking* like e.g. `int64_t`, is not allowed as second parameter for your template.

Comment: Tryied to fix but the compiler now gives more errors then before, I edited the question.

Comment: @Arack `int128_t` is a class. You can't pass a class instance as a non-type template parameter - it's unrelated to `constexpr`.

Comment: @Arack the method definitions in your code still define `template <class T, T modulus>` which is wrong now. The `static_cast` in your main does not have the closing `>` but a `)`. And if you fix that it seems you get a infinite for loop. If you take that one out as well it compiles and runs fine: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/789b0c771730ccc9